# Matrix series which exhibits finitely many non-zero terms

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

If $A=C-\frac{1}{2}C^2+\frac{1}{3}C^3-\frac{1}{4}C^4+\cdots$ where

C=$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & c & c^2 \\
 0 & 0 & c \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

(i) I want to show that A possesses finitely many terms apart from $0$. 
(ii) How can I compute A?
(iii) How can I also illustrate that $A-\frac{1}{2!}A^2+\frac{1}{3!}A^3-\frac{1}{4!}A^4+\cdots$ exhibits finitely many non-zero terms.
(iv) How can I also show that $A-\frac{1}{2!}A^2+\frac{1}{3!}A^3-\frac{1}{4!}A^4+\cdots=C$?

Comment: Compute  $C^2$ and $C^3$ and you should see the trick.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You may suppose $c\ne0$. Rewrite $C$ as $\;c\begin{pmatrix}0&1&c\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, and check $C^3=0$, so $A$ is indeed a finite sum.

Answer (score 1):

A [strictly upper triangular matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Strictly_triangular_matrix) like $C$ is always nilpotent, meaning that $C^k=0$ for some finite $k$. More generally, $M^n=0$ for any $n\times n$ strictly upper (or lower) triangular matrix, then $C^3=0$ and 
$$
A= C - \frac{1}{2}C^2.
$$

This answers (i) and (ii). As $A$ is a polynomial of a nilpotent matrix, it is itself nilpotent, what answers (iii). Now realize that $A^3=0$ and $A^2=C^2$, then
$$
A-\frac{1}{2}A^2=C-C^2\neq C.
$$
Thus (iv) is *not* correct.